# Calling all list elements in a line to put into a function

Tags: jython, imagej

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I am very new at this. I am using jython to code for imagej, if that helps.

I have paths to some videos stored in a list and I need to put them all in a line (with "," separation) to apply one of imagej plugins to it, like so:

```
def stich(path):
my_list = function_that_returns_a_list(path) 
output = Concatenator.run(my_lis[1],my_list[2],my_list[3]....)
return output
```

The only problem is: I can not figure out how to put all my_list content, one by one (as above), into code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use :

```
output = Concatenator.run(*my_list)
```

Comment: I should probably clarify, that `Concatenator` is a not user defined function, but an imagej plugin which can be found [here](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJ/blob/master/ij/plugin/Concatenator.java). 
The problem is that because `Concatenator` is a java function it is rally picky about the input and that is why I need the list I input into it to be strictly [my_list1,my_list2..]

Comment: Oh ! Then it is easy. You just have to call 
output = Concatenator.run(*my_list)

Comment: I can't belive it was that simple.... Thank you !